# NVIDIA Adaptive power management not working with 3 monitors?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, power-management

I have 3 monitors 1920 - 3860 - 1920 and when all 3 are connected NVIDIAs adaptive power management is not working anymore. It always is at max even when idling on desktop.

As soon as I disconnect one of the 3 monitors the heat returns to normal and the fan even totally stops.

*Is there a way to make this work with 3 monitors?*

System info:

- Kubuntu 17.10 with backports
- NVIDIA Driver 396.18 from repository
- GeForce GTX 970

**Update:** I am now on Kubuntu 18.04 and have the NVIDIA driver 390.48 But still the same problem.

**Update:**
What I mean by "max" is the performance level that is kept at 3 if more than 2 monitors are connected

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the screenshot, I just noticed that the "Clock speed" Indeed does drop down even though the Performance level keeps being stuck at 3. This is most likely due to the Memory requirement for feeding the 3 Monitors. So the Memory transfer rate stays as 7010 and so the Performace level is showing 3.

Luckily the clock speed is throttled independently from the Memory transfer rate. So the Performance Level is a bit misleading. There actually should be two independent Performance level shown. Or I still don't get something.

Now I also notice the "min"/"Max" columns in Graphics Clock and am even more confused. But I guess this is to set an upper bound for laptops when locking to a certain performance level...